# How to take data from a website and put it into Sheets

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to make a spreadsheet where you enter an ID of a steam page. For example: `257850` which would result in the link `http://store.steampowered.com/app/257850/` and it would show you the Discount Final Price, Price without discount and the % of discount.

So I'm starting with Discount Final Price and I think I need to scrape the data using IMPORTXML but I've no idea how the "URL" portion of it works. I've figured out that to get the data I need to use XPATH like this (I used data-miner.io to check it if works, and it does):

```
//*[@id="game_area_purchase"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]
```

but I can't seem to get the URL portion to work. Here's how I'm trying to make it work:

```
=importXML("http://store.steampowered.com/app/257850/"; "//*[@id="game_area_purchase"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2])"
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use this function:

```
 =IMPORTXML("http://store.steampowered.com/app/"&A1,"//*[@class='discount_final_price']")
```

you will see I added A1 in there as the cell that would have your id - in this case it was 257850 but you can point to any cell you want

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the div directly with `class='discount_final_price'. You've also got some of the syntax wrong in your function. The one below works.

`=importXML("http://store.steampowered.com/app/257850/","//*[@class='discount_final_price']")`

Example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17ofeTliQcMJ_-W7AVDB1Nvkq-4xHRgiRtt8DP6NpTAk/edit#gid=0).

Comment: lol we both answered at the exact same time with the same answer :-P

Answer (score -1):

There is a utility called [import.io](https://www.import.io/) that can do this for you. It's possible to get this free.

Comment: it's much easier to do it in a google sheet with a simple importxml call